# Loop calculation with previous value not using for in R

Tags: r, loops, recursion, reduce

I'm a beginning R programmer. I have trouble in a loop calculation with a previous value like recursion. 
An example of my data:

```
 dt <- data.table(a = c(0:4), b = c( 0, 1, 2, 1, 3))
```

And calculated value 'c' is y[n] = (y[n-1] + b[n])*a[n]. Initial value of c is 0. (c[1] = 0)

I used the for loop and the code and result is as below.

```
dt$y <- 0
for (i in 2:nrow(dt)) {
  dt$y[i] <- (dt$y[i - 1] + dt$b[i]) * dt$a[i]
}

   a b  y
1: 0 0  0
2: 1 1  1
3: 2 2  6
4: 3 1 21
5: 4 3 96
```

This result is what I want. However, my data has over 1,000,000 rows and several columns, therefore I'm trying to find other ways without using a for loop. I tried to use "Reduce()", but it only works with a single vector (ex. y[n] = y_[n-1]+b[n]). As shown above, my function uses two vectors, a and b, so I can't find a solution.

Is there a more efficient way to be faster without using a for loop, such as using a recursive function or any good package functions?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution.

1. According to the information from [@ThetaFC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59760090/12158757), an indication for speedup is to use matrix or vector (rather than `data.frame` for `data.table`). Thus, it is better to have the following preprocessing before calculating `df$y`, i.e.,

```
a <- as.numeric(df$a)
b <- as.numeric(df$b)
```

2. Then, you have two approaches to get `df$y`:

   - writing your customized recursion function

```
f <- function(k) {
  if (k == 1) return(0)
  c(f(k-1),(tail(f(k-1),1) + b[k])*a[k])
}

df$y <- f(nrow(df))
```

- Or a non-recursion function (I guess this will be much faster then the recursive approach)

```
g <- Vectorize(function(k) sum(rev(cumprod(rev(a[2:k])))*b[2:k]))

df$y <- g(seq(nrow(df)))
```

such that

```
> df
  a b  y
1 0 0  0
2 1 1  1
3 2 2  6
4 3 1 21
5 4 3 96
```

Comment: On a ```df``` with just 20,000 rows, your 2nd solution took 27 seconds on my machine, using the toy example in the answer I provided below.  It's much faster to access the vectors through a matrix or as individual numeric vectors (0.02 seconds).  Appears that indexing the data.frame or data.table is the speed bottleneck--not the for loop

Comment: @ThetaFC thanks for your information, and now my answer is updated

Answer (score 2):

This kind of computation cannot make use of R's advantage of vectorization because of the iterative dependencies.  But the slow-down appears to really be coming from indexing performance on a `data.frame` or `data.table`.

Interestingly, I was able to speed up the loop considerably by accessing `a`, `b`, and `y` directly as numeric `vectors` (1000+ fold advantage for 2*10^5 rows) or as `matrix` "columns" (100+ fold advantage for 2*10^5 rows) versus as columns in a `data.table` or `data.frame`.

This old discussion may still shed some light on this rather surprising result: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-July/282666.html

Please note that I also made a different toy `data.frame`, so I could test a larger example without returning `Inf` as `y` grew with `i`:

Option `data.frame` (numeric vectors embedded in a `data.frame` or `data.table` per your example):

```
vec_length <- 200000
dt <- data.frame(a=seq(from=0, to=1, length.out = vec_length), b=seq(from=0, to=-1, length.out = vec_length), y=0)
system.time(for (i in 2:nrow(dt)) {
  dt$y[i] <- (dt$y[i - 1] + dt$b[i]) * dt$a[i]
})
#user  system elapsed 
#79.39  146.30  225.78
#NOTE: Sorry, I didn't have the patience to let the data.table version finish for vec_length=2*10^5.  
tail(dt$y)
#[1] -554.1953 -555.1842 -556.1758 -557.1702 -558.1674 -559.1674
```

Option `vector` (`numeric` vectors extracted in advance of loop):

```
vec_length <- 200000
dt <- data.frame(a=seq(from=0, to=1, length.out = vec_length), b=seq(from=0, to=-1, length.out = vec_length), y=0)
y <- as.numeric(dt$y)
a <- as.numeric(dt$a)
b <- as.numeric(dt$b)
system.time(for (i in 2:length(y)) {
  y[i] <- (y[i - 1] + b[i]) * a[i]
})
#user  system elapsed 
#0.03    0.00    0.03 
tail(y)
#[1] -554.1953 -555.1842 -556.1758 -557.1702 -558.1674 -559.1674
```

Option `matrix` (`data.frame` converted to `matrix` before loop):

```
vec_length <- 200000
dt <- as.matrix(data.frame(a=seq(from=0, to=1, length.out = vec_length), b=seq(from=0, to=-1, length.out = vec_length), y=0))
system.time(for (i in 2:nrow(dt)) {
  dt[i, 1] <- (dt[i - 1, 3] + dt[i, 2]) * dt[i, 1]
})
#user  system elapsed 
#0.67    0.01    0.69
tail(dt[,3])
#[1] -554.1953 -555.1842 -556.1758 -557.1702 -558.1674 -559.1674
#NOTE: a matrix is actually a vector but with an additional attribute (it's "dim") that says how the "matrix" should be organized into rows and columns
```

Option `data.frame` with matrix style indexing:

```
vec_length <- 200000
dt <- data.frame(a=seq(from=0, to=1, length.out = vec_length), b=seq(from=0, to=-1, length.out = vec_length), y=0)
system.time(for (i in 2:nrow(dt)) {
    dt[i, 3] <- (dt[(i - 1), 3] + dt[i, 2]) * dt[i, 1]
})
#user  system elapsed 
#110.69    0.03  112.01 
tail(dt[,3])
#[1] -554.1953 -555.1842 -556.1758 -557.1702 -558.1674 -559.1674
```

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use `Rcpp` since for this recursive equation is easy to code in C++:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("
NumericVector func(NumericVector b, NumericVector a) {
    int len = b.size();
    NumericVector y(len);

    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        y[i] = (y[i-1] + b[i]) * a[i];
    }

    return(y);
}
")
func(c( 0, 1, 2, 1, 3), c(0:4))
#[1]  0  1  6 21 96
```

timing code:

```
vec_length <- 1e7
dt <- data.frame(a=1:vec_length, b=1:vec_length, y=0)
y <- as.numeric(dt$y)
a <- as.numeric(dt$a)
b <- as.numeric(dt$b)

system.time(for (i in 2:length(y)) {
    y[i] <- (y[i - 1] + b[i]) * a[i]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  19.22    0.06   19.44 

system.time(func(b, a))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.09    0.02    0.09
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will be any faster, but here's one way to do it without an explicit loop

```
dt[, y := purrr::accumulate2(a, b, function(last, a, b) (last + b)*a
                             , .init = 0)[-1]]

dt      
#    a b  y
# 1: 0 0  0
# 2: 1 1  1
# 3: 2 2  6
# 4: 3 1 21
# 5: 4 3 96
```